# Find minimal polynomial of given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I want to find the minimal polynomial of this matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

I found it charastic polynomial $\chi_{A}=\left(2-x\right)^{3}\left(3-x\right)^{2}$

I also know that the minimal polynomial irreducible factors have the same irreducible factors as charastic polynomial so
$$m_{A}\left(x\right)\in\left\{ \left(2-x\right)^{3}\left(3-x\right)^{2},\left(2-x\right)^{3}\left(3-x\right),\left(2-x\right)^{2}\left(3-x\right),\left(2-x\right)\left(3-x\right),\left(2-x\right)\left(3-x\right)^{2}\right\}  $$
but I don't know how to continue from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is $(X-2)^3(X-3)$. This a triangular matrix with a $2\times 2$ diagonal block whose eigenvalue is $3$ thus whose minimal polynomial is $X-3$. There exists a block which is a $3\times 3$ matrix which has $2$ on the diagonal. The minimal polynomial of this block is $(X-2)^3$.

Comment: can you explain how do you know the minimal polynomial of the $3\times3$ matrix is $\left(X-2\right)^{3}$

Comment: Let $A$ be that $3\times 3$ matrix. I have computed $(A-2), (A-2)^2, (A-2)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in a glance that the generalised eigenspace for $\lambda=2$ is spanned by the first three vectors of the canonical basis, and that for $\lambda=3$ by the last two; the minimal polynomial is the product of the minimal polynomials of the restrictions to these generalised eigenspaces. For the former the minimal polynomial is $(X-2)^3$ because $(A-2)^2$ does not kill the first standard basis vector; for the latter the restriction is $3$ times the identity, so the minimal polynomial is $X-3$. Their product is $(X-2)^3(X-3)$.